# Segfault while composing vector of lambda functions

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, functional-programming, higher-order-functions

I am trying to create a `compose_all` lambda that accepts a vector of functions, and returns a single function that is the composition of all of the functions in the vector:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::function;
using std::vector;

int main() {
  vector<function<int(int)>> functions = {
    [](int x) { return 2 * x; },
    [](int x) { return x * x; },
    [](int x) { return -x; },
  };

  function<function<int(int)>(
      vector<function<int(int)>>::iterator,
      vector<function<int(int)>>::iterator,
      function<int(int)>)> compose_all;
  compose_all = [&](vector<function<int(int)>>::iterator f_begin,
                    vector<function<int(int)>>::iterator f_end,
                    function<int(int)> f) -> function<int(int)> {
    for (; f_begin < f_end; ++f_begin) {
      f = [&](int x) { return (*f_begin)(f(x)); };
    }
    return f;
  };

  auto composition = compose_all(functions.begin(),
                                 functions.end(),
                                 [](int x) { return x; });

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    cout << composition(i) << endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

While this compiles fine, it segfaults:

```
$ clang++ -std=c++11 -g composition.cpp && ./a.out 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

What is the cause for the segfault, and what would be the fix?

Notes from debugging with print statements and GDB:

- The iterators are correctly received by `compose_all`
- The segfault occurs on the line `f = [&](int x) { return (*f_begin)(f(x)); };`
- Separately dereferencing `f_begin` yields correct results (it calls the correct lambda in the vector)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each lambda created by

```
f = [&](int x) { return (*f_begin)(f(x)); };
```

captures `f` and `f_begin` by reference, where both are local to the body of the lambda you stored in `compose_all`.

The last of these functions gets returned by the body of `compose_all`'s contained lambda when it is called, then gets assigned to `composition`. But since the body of `compose_all`'s lambda has exited, the lifetime of `f` and `f_begin` has ended, and invoking `composition` is undefined behavior.

Besides, you don't really want `f` to call itself, which would just get you infinite recursion. You want `f` to call a copy of the value of `f` from its current value (that is, the initial value, or from the previous time you assigned `f`).

You need something like:

```
const auto& g = *f_begin;
f = [=](int x) { return g(f(x)); };
```

(Or in C++14 or later, this could be written:)

```
f = [f, g=*f_begin](int x) { return g(f(x)); };
```

Comment: Good catch re. the `[&]`! 
This modification was sufficient to fix it:
`f = [=](int x) { return (*f_begin)(f(x)); };`

Comment: @joydeepb Okay, but I'd prefer not to capture an iterator, either. If your `functions` vector changes at all, the `compositions` functor will probably be just as dead.

Comment: @ascepler That is true.